# Paypal Payflow refund issue

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payflowlink

Hi am trying to create a refunding function for the paypal payflow.

This is code what exactly am created.

```
public function refund()
{
    $this->load->helper('paypal_helper');
    $request = array(
        "PARTNER"           => PARTNER,
        "VENDOR"            => VENDOR,
        "USER"              => USER,
        "PWD"               => PWD, 
        "TRXTYPE"           => 'C',
        "AMT"               => '11',
        "CURRENCY"          => CURRENCY,
        "CREATESECURETOKEN" => "N",
        "SECURETOKENID"     => uniqid('213'.time()),
        "RETURNURL"         => site_url().'test/refund',
        "CANCELURL"         => site_url().'test/refund',
        "ERRORURL"          => site_url().'test/refund',
        "ORIGID"            => 'A70A6DBF0A8C'
    );
    $response = run_payflow_call($request);
    printr($response);
    return $response;
}
```

Here ORGID is set as the PNREF what i got after the success payment.

`$response = run_payflow_call($request);` is defined in the helper and it just post the details in to the https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/ (sandbox). But after the action i got the result like this 
`[RESULT] => 23
 [PNREF] => A1X06F928D52
 [RESPMSG] => Invalid account number`

Any one can tell me why this happen ??

am using the same "PARTNER"  "VENDOR" "USER" for the purchase section also. But in the purchase everything going fine. I get the success report and the amount properly credited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refund a transaction using the Payflow you just need to pass the below parameters :

TRXTYPE =C  (value is "C" for credit )

TENDER  =C  ( Value can be "C" if the payment was done using the credit card or "P" if its a       PayPal payment)

ORIGID  = A70A6DBF0A8C( Id to refund)

AMT     = Optional parameter ( If not provided whole amount will be refunded)

Secure token is not required while doing the refund .

Comment: suppose i pass the ORGID in the request did the paypal default take the account (the same account that the payment done) ?? or i need to pass the account ACCT and EXPDATE ??

Comment: Yes PayPal will automatically refund to the account from which the original payment was done . So need not pass any credit card related information explicitly .